# FactoryGirl trouble

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I have a class that is defined in the module.

```
module Mod
  class Zed
   include DataMapper::Resource
  end
end
```

For testing, I define factory.

```
#/factories/zed.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :zed do
   #code 
  end
end
```

But when I start testing I get an error.

```
describe 'Zed' do
  it "should have ..." do
    FactoryGirl.create(:zed)
  end
end
```

Error:

```
 Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:zed)
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Zed
```

How to test a class that is included in the module?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should specify class when defining a factory like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :zed, class: Mod::Zed do
   #code 
  end
end
```